# Copy unique list to any location

Tags: excel, vba

There are a lot of solutions on here that are very very close but all I can find has the unique list headed to a pre-set location.

Example Data

Animal
Dog
Dog
Cat
Duck
Goose
Duck
Cat
Duck

I want to be able to grab this list (column header included) with a standard Ctrl + C, go to another location, run a macro and have it paste a unique list into the range required so I would get:

Animal
Dog
Cat
Duck
Goose

Tried using the macro recorder and parsing out the relevant parts but no dice, and the code generates cell-specific references which I'm too much of a noob to figure out how to replace. I want this to work dynamically regardless of the location in any sheet, like a 'paste unique' command with something I've already selected.

To clarify further, it would be great if I could paste an already non-duplicate list into the current location. The basic idea would be to grab a column from say 400 rows of data, paste a unique list of its values into another place and then be able to start creating summary tabulations (counts, sums, etc) using that list.

Also I'm using Excel 2010.

Adding macro-recorded code below:

```
Sub Macro6()  
' Macro6 Macro  
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select  
    Selection.Copy  
    Range("A2").Select  
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select  
    Range("A438").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$438:$A$866").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _  
        xlYes  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you recorded.  This helps us see that you've tried something, but also allows us to edit your code and make some comments to help you learn how to avoid using cell-specific references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to grab this list (column header included) with a
>   standard Ctrl + C, go to another location, run a macro and have it
>   paste a unique list into the range required

I guess this special macro for pasting should do what you want, supposing the data is on one column:

```
Sub PasteAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Selection.Parent.Paste
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error with this saying "Paste method of Worksheet class failed"

Comment: @Crazysasman, to have it work you should selected some range with Ctrl+C and have it "flashing", then go to another location and Select it  (while the original is still flashing) and then execute the macro.

Comment: I'm want to avoid selecting anything for the paste - I don't know how big the unique list will be so I don't know what to select. I just want it to drop into the sheet starting with the column header at whatever cell is currently selected.

Comment: You only need to select the first cell... the top cell where you will paste the list ;) @Crazysasman

Comment: You only need to select the first cell, Otherwise I dont see how you will indicate where you want to paste the (filtered) data?

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm getting the same error regardless of what method I try here. I think what you are describing 'select the first cell only' is what I tried first and got that error above

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, it is because when you open the Macro Dialog Excel stops the copy mode.  I didnt expect that, I just tried to launch the macro from the debugger. The workaround (I tried it and it works) is to assign to this macro a shortcut key, such as ctrl+p. You can do that in the following way:

Comment: open the macro dialog, select the macro `PasteAndRemoveDuplicates` and click options. Set the shortcut key to ctrl+p. Then when you select the top cell of the destination, while the source range still flashing, just type ctrl+p.

Comment: That does it - thanks! The only other feature (not sure if its doable without a lot more work) would be to not overwrite cells that are 'below' the selection. Is there some way to de-dup *before* pasting?

Comment: Sure it is doable but in this case we maybe need to remove the duplicates programmatically using an array. The problem is, how can you be sure that the resulting de-duplicated range will not exceed the available blank range?

Comment: The code wouldn't need to check for that or guard against it - most data I work with I know roughly what to expect in terms of unique values. I just don't want to overwrite something that is say 30 cells down when I know my unique list is only going to take a dozen or so rows.

Comment: After thinking of it, it seems the easy way would be to pass through some intermediate range, that is some range that we can dedicate to the operation and we know will never be used for actual data. Is that an option? Otherwise indeed the operation seems more complex.

Comment: I guess you could throw it way over on the right side of the sheet like in column XFD or something? Another thing that would be awesome is to make this work for multiple columns at once. I think I should take my learnings from this and post another more well-formed question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA routine for this.

Place the routine in a standard code module.

```
Sub Crazy()
    With Selection.CurrentRegion
        If .Count > 1 Then
            .RemoveDuplicates 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Now...

Copy your list of animals and paste it wherever you like.

Select at least one of the cells in the list.

Run the Crazy procedure from the Macro Dialog (Control-F8).

That's it.

Comment: This seems to only filter the list in place - if I copy something and try to go to another sheet or area of that same sheet and call the macro it just returns a single blank cells  ***edit*** sorry - I see now all I have to do is paste it first. I can probably figure out how to add that part to the macro.